# Why does the duration of a unit test result not equal the difference between start and end time?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, vs-unit-testing-framework

I've written a test for a long running process. when it completes, I get the following displayed in the test results:

```
Test Run: [blah]
Test Name: PopulateDataTest
Result: Passed
Duration: 00:03:17.0017261
Computer Name: [name here]
Start Time: 3/8/2011 12:54:18 PM
End Time: 3/8/2011 1:02:31 PM
```

Doing some math on the start and end dates, I get about 8 minutes, not 3. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @Matt Spinelli said, I suspect that the reported duration value also reflects the amount of time that the CPU actually spent executing the test, rather than the End Time - Start Time of the test. That is, I think that CPU time is the metric being reported, since that is the more important thing. If your computer happens to start updating Adobe Acrobat (or whatever) during the test then that could inappropriately be reflected in the End Time - Start Time value.

On the other hand, I have little knowledge of Visual Studio testing framework. I do not know how the test mechanism would deal with the execution time of multi-threaded processes, for example. So coming from me, this is all just speculation.

Comment: this makes more sense. I was running some other significant stuff in the background, which was spiking my CPU. thanks

Answer (score 0):

MSTest has some initialization that goes on each time you run the test suite (i.e. creating folders for the test run, copying files/assemblies, starting and updating the unit testing pane, etc).

I agree that this is irritating as I've seen this behavior too. I presume you have a pretty good number of tests, files, and/or assemblies. If you are using Microsoft Moles, this too seems to slow down the initiation speed.

Comment: That doesn't quite make sense. I have written other tests that take milliseconds to complete. Why would those not add 5 minutes as well?

Comment: Where those other tests part of a large codebase and/or test suite? In any case I'm currently using VS2008. It doesn't have Duration time field for the entire test run (that I can find anyway). So maybe that's a new feature. In my experience the sum of the individual test durations (exported to excel) were always less than the Start-End times of the test suite run.

Comment: In this case, I was comparing it to only running one unit test at a time.
Jeffrey's answer makes a lot of sense meaning that the timer is considered part of the Unit tests threat, getting paused when the processor puts it on hold.